# Python- selenium http authentication not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, centos, firefox-profile

I tried to authenticate a webpage(oracle BI dashboard) using Python selenium webdriver for Firefox. The module is running on CentOS. 
I wrote the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('network.http.phishy-userpass-length', 255)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("http://username:pwd@abc.com")
```

It is going to the website but not logging in. I went through tens of threads on stackoverflow regarding this but none of the methods worked.

Comment: have you tried to fill username/password fields with `send_keys` method or it's not applicable in your case?

Comment: driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://username:pwd@abc.com')
wait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
alert = driver.switch_to_alert()
alert.send_keys('username')
alert.send_keys(Keys.TAB)
alert.send_keys('pwd')
alert.accept() 


I get the below error. Is it because the version mismatch between selenium and python?
>>> wait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/u/lni/python-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.47.1-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 76 raise

Comment: I guess this is not full error log, so I can't make suggestions..

Comment: This is the full error log
>>> wait(driver, 5).until(EC.alert_is_present())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/u/lni/python-2.7.5/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.47.1-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 76, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: There is a login page on your website or just popup prompt for entering user's credentials?

Comment: It is a login page on the website.

Comment: I tried to get to few websites with `FirefoxProfile` authentication method, but it seems that it only works with popup login dialog-boxes.. You should identify your username/passwords input fields elements with `driver.find_element_by_...()` and input user's credentials with `send_keys()`. This should work anyway

Comment: Are you sure that HTTP Basic authentication is actually used? As you say you have a login form, that seems rather unlikely to me.